# ie7 Png transparency image

Tags: internet-explorer-7, png, transparency

PNG image transparency does not work on IE7.  It look like this on IE7:

http://websitehelp.techgrowthglobal.com/bc_developers/index.html

In the column right portion of the body there is a curved image on top-a1

In the center it was the repeat png background and at the bottom was a curve also a3

It doesn't work on IE7.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting 404 errors for all your PNG files. I believe the answer here is.. check to see if you are referencing their paths correctly in your code... because IE7 has a "quite solid"[(see here)](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2005/04/26/412263.aspx) implementation of PNG support.

Click here for 404..
http://websitehelp.techgrowthglobal.com/bc_developers/images/bg_curve1b.png

Answer (score 0):

It believe it's the URLs for your background images. IE 6, and quite possibly 7, incorrectly treats relative URLs in CSS files as being relative to the document's location, rather than relative to the CSS file's location (which is [the correct way according to CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri)). In your case, your CSS contains paths like

```
../images/some-image-file.png
```

Relative to the CSS URL path

```
/bc_developers/css/global.css
```

this should resolve to

```
/bc_developers/images/some-image-file.png
```

but as your document is located at

```
 /bc_developers/index.html
```

the path will, in IE, resolve instead to

```
/images/some-image-file.png
```

leading to the 404s described by snicker.

Changing the relative paths in your CSS from

```
../images/some-image-file.png
```

to absolute paths like

```
/bc_developers/images/some-image-file.png
```

should fix things.